# Question about Lagrange multiplier and maximum point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum of $\log{x}+\log{y}+3\log{z}$ on portion of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =5r^2$

where $x,y,z>o $

I found that maximum is $5\log{r} + 3\log{\sqrt{3}}$ at $(r,r,3\sqrt{3})$

And Use this result to prove that for real positive $a, b, c$,

$abc^3$ is less than or equal to $27(a+b+\frac{c}{5})^5$

Can anyone help me prove this inequality given that we have a maximum?

Answer (score 0):

There are two typos:

The maximum happens at $(r,r,\sqrt{3}r)$, and the right hand side of the inequality should be $27(\frac{a+b+c}{5})^5$.

Suppose $a=x^2,b=y^2,c=z^2$. Use the fact that $\log{x}+\log{y}+3\log{z}\leq 5\log{r} + 3\log{\sqrt{3}}$ when $x,y,z$ satisfies the sphere equation.

So

$$\log{xyz^3}\leq\log{3\sqrt{3}r^5}\\
\Rightarrow \log{x^2y^2z^6}\leq \log{27r^{10}}\\
\Rightarrow \log{abc^3}\leq \log{27(\frac{a+b+c}{5})^5}\\
\Rightarrow abc^3\leq 27(\frac{a+b+c}{5})^5$$

I used the fact that $r^2=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{5}$

Some log properties I used:

$$\log{a+b}=\log{a}+\log{b}\\
\log{a^r}=r\log{a}$$

Comment: how come the right hand inequality is 27(a+b+c/5)^5? I cant see it

Comment: If my understanding is correct, it is $27(\frac{a+b+c}{5})^5$ instead of $27(a+b+\frac{c}{5})^5$? In this case, $r^2=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{5}=\frac{a+b+c}{5}$.

Comment: yes you are right. If we let a=x^2, then x=sqr(a), y=sqr(b), z=sqr(c), then logx+logy+3logz would be (1/2)loga+(1/2)logb+(1/2logc and also, I still don't understand how it is implied that 27(a+b+c/5)^5 is greater

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it